# Proving the correctness of an algorithm, which computes the connectivity of a directed graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, correctness-proof

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a directed graph. The **connectivity** of a graph is the defined as the cardinality of a smallest separator of $G$. A **separator** of $G$ is a subset $U$ of $V$, such that $G-U$ is not strongly connected.

Why does the following algorithm compute the connectivity of a graph correctly?

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\text{Connectivity}(\text{graph }G=(V,E)) \\
&\;\;\;\;01\text{:}\;\;k=\infty \\
&\;\;\;\;02\text{:}\;\;\text{for }i=1,\ldots,|V| \\
&\;\;\;\;03\text{:}\;\;\{\\
&\;\;\;\;04\text{:}\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{for each }v\in V\\
&\;\;\;\;05\text{:}\;\;\;\;\;\;\{\\
&\;\;\;\;06\text{:}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{compute a minimum }v_i,v\text{-seperator }U_{v_i,v}\\
&\;\;\;\;07\text{:}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;k=\min\left\{k,\left|U_{v_i,v}\right|\right\}\\
&\;\;\;\;08\text{:}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{if }(i>k+1) \text{ return }k\\
&\;\;\;\;09\text{:}\;\;\\
&\;\;\;\;10\text{:}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{compute a minimum }v,v_i\text{-seperator }U_{v,v_i}\\
&\;\;\;\;11\text{:}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;k=\min\left\{k,\left|U_{v,v_i}\right|\right\}\\
&\;\;\;\;12\text{:}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{if }(i>k+1) \text{ return }k\\
&\;\;\;\;13\text{:}\;\;\;\;\;\;\}\\
&\;\;\;\;14\text{:}\;\;\}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

More precisely, why can we return $k$ in line 08 (resp. 12) without concerning the other $u,v$-seperators?

Comment: Try to understand why the algorithm works and then you should be able to prove that it does.

Comment: Don't use images as a substitute for text or algorithms. Not only is it lazy, it also makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and maths (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the algorithm is incorrect. We can slightly modify the algorithm by moving lines 8,12 just after the inner loop. If the algorithm returns $k$ incorrectly at the end of step $i$, then there must exist vertices $v_s,v_t$, for $s,t>i$, and a set $S$ of size $k-1$ not containing $v_s,v_t$, such that after removing $S$ there is no path from $v_s$ to $v_t$. I claim that $v_1,\ldots,v_i \in S$: if $v_j \notin S$ for some $j \leq i$, then since $S$ does not disconnect $v_j$ from any other vertex, we would have a path $v_s \to v_j \to v_t$. Since $v_1,\ldots,v_i \in S$, in particular $|S| \geq i$. Stated differently, $k-1 \geq i$. So if $i > k-1$, this is impossible.

My proof, if correct, shows that you can actually use the weaker condition $i > k-1$ in lines 8,12.